# How can i convert int to char? as in guess in my question

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I change `while (guess != 404)` to a `char` like `(guess != Q)`? Is it possible to do so? If yes, please help me out. So when i enter Q it should not proceed to the next.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int answer, guess,  attemptsNum = 0;
        final int maxAttempts = 5;
        String str,  another = "y";


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        answer = generator.nextInt(5) + 1;

        while (another.equals("y") || another.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 5");

            System.out.println("Enter your guess (404 to quit):");

            guess = scan.nextInt();
            attemptsNum = 0;
            while (guess != 404)

            {
                attemptsNum++;
                if (guess == answer) {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    break;
                } else if (guess != answer)
                    System.out.println("Wrong");
                if (attemptsNum == maxAttempts) {
                    System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
                    break;

                }

                System.out.println("Enter your guess (0 to quit):");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Want to Play again?(y/n)");
            another = scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want `guess` to be a `char` why are you declaring and reading it as an `int`?

Comment: Do you mean to assign 404 to a character? if so then go ahead and declare a variable `int Q = 404` if you're not then 404 is out of alphabet boundary for ascii value. You may not compare the input to 'Q' (ascii 81) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scan.next()` which returns a `String`:

```
guess = scan.next();
```

Then you can do:

```
while (!guess.equals("Q")){
    ...
}
```

Also, you might want to have a look at `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`.